# What's the point of XP in Freeway Fury 2?

Tags: freeway-fury-2

I am playing [Freeway Fury 2](http://www.notdoppler.com/freewayfury2.php) and I noticed that every time I die, I get XP.

What is it used for? What do I gain with higher XP?

[image: freewayfury]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It gives you special bonuses in Free Ride mode.
[image]

Comment: So it doesn't help me any in the main mode? :(

Comment: @AshleyNunn: Nope, you need skillz like me. :P